# Recursive Algorithm to count nodes less than the given value

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

> Hello, I am studying for my final exam, so from my previous exam, I
>   got partial credit for this problem.  recursive algorithm such that it
>   counts how many nodes of a given linked list have info values less
>   than the given threshold value

```
 typedef struct LLNode {
       int info;
       struct LLNode* pNext;
    }LLNode;

    int recCount(LLNode *front, int threshold)
     {  


     }
```

> my answer was

```
int count = 0;
int total_less;
if(front == NULL)
 return 0 ;
if(count < threshold) 
   count = 1 + recCount(front->next, front->info); 
   total_less++;

return total_
```

Comment: After you got your results, did you run your program and try to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter version:

If value is smaller, add +1 to result and check the next node in the list, else just check for next node without adding to count.

```
int recCount(struct NODE *N, int value)
{
    if(N == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(N->data < value)
        return 1 + recCount(N->next, value);

    return recCount(N->next, value);
}
```

Example code:
http://tpcg.io/36qFkO

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you are not sending `threshold` to recursive calls.

```
recCount(front->next, front->info);
```

And I'm not sure why below condition is supposed to be there.

```
if(count < threshold)  //as count is initialized to 0.
```

**Example of recursive:**

```
 int recCount(LLNode *front, int threshold)
 {
    int count = 0;

    if(front == NULL)
    return 0 ;

    if (front->info < threshold)
    count++;

    count = count + recCount(front->next, threshold);

    return count;
 }
```